# How to start forming a django website and how django structures pages?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I started a django project for my personal website to learn django. So far I've got my development environment set with everything I need and followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) great tutorial to create some basic data structures and templates. Now I would like to start using my html layout I made before and start implementing the functionalities to it. However I'm having hard time understanding how to accomplish this.

I've mostly done java portal solutions before this where I could start the server, create some pages, set my theme for them and then add custom portlets (the functionalities/code) wherever I wanted. In django, I've created a view with my html layout and it works fine. I however don't understand how I should handle pages. Do I need to create a separate view for each in url and view configs and then use the same html layout for each page and only set different functionalities wherever needed? Doesn't seem like django way since less is more.  I guess I can use the views somehow a bit like portlets so that they are part of some page (which is a view itself?) right? Like a poll in a certain part of a page. How?

So for example I want to have a frontpage where I have a certain "theme" (html-layout) and maybe latest blog posts there. Then another page named resources where there is the same "theme" and a list of downloadable content. Naturally a navigation somewhere in the layout to switch between pages.

I'd be much obliged if someone could point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using Django template inheritance. You will do a "home" template, and will use `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` to define where the blog posts will be. In the template where you will display the blog posts (which is a separate HTML file), you will put `{%extends "home.html"%}` and the same `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`, and inside `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`, you will put the HTML code for your blog posts.

When Django loads the home page, it will look where else you have that block named "content" in other templates and will load whatever is inside them, which in this case, is your blog posts.

Let me show you a little example:

home.html

```
<title>Home</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .content-wrapper{
        text-decoration:none;
    border: 1px none;
        height: 50%;
        left: 0%;
        position: relative;
        top: 8%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

and blog-posts.html

```
{%extends "home.html"%}
 <head>PUT HERE ALL THE CSS STYLESHEETS YOU'LL BE USING AND PUT THEM ALSO IN HOME.HTML</head>
<body>
   {%block content%}
      HTML FOR YOUR BLOG POSTS
   {%endblock%}
</body>
```

This way you will have to do separate templates, but will do much less code. And you will have to point them in urls.py, because they will behave almost like frames.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blog-posts/','Mod031.views.blog-posts'),
    url(r'^home/', 'Mod031.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

You will have, also, a view to load each template you need

```
def home (request):
return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def blog-posts(request):
return render_to_response('blog-posts.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

For further information, please, read the docs: [The Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language)

Comment: Thank you very much for a thorough answer! Somehow I just failed to see the whole picture here although now it all seems pretty clear. I was hoping there was a way of managing pages in another way than using urls.py and views.py configs for example so that if one wanted to create a site where ordinary users could create simple pages which uses functionalities like the blog posts mentioned before, they could just use the admin panel or such to do so. Maybe someone has already made such addons themselves. I however am perfectly fine with the template system now that I understand it so thank you!

Comment: Oh, I'm glad I could help! I was thinking a little more about it, after I sent the answer. You will only need one view for each template if you plan to associate them with links, like in a menu. When you click an option from a menu, that option will have an `a href` that would lead to the sub-template which would be rendered inside the content block I mentioned before.