# How to handle additional blocks in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

I'm learning Django now and have a simple question: how to handle additional page blocks (besides the main content block) in Django?

Let me explain what i mean. Assume we have a page "/news/view/12" which refers to "news.views.view" view function. 
At this page i'm going to have blocks like navigation menu, recent blog posts, footer with some info and so on. In other words - these blocks will be placed at every page on the site.
And, of course, there will be the main content block with the content of the news item.

In this view function ("news.views.view") i want to have a Python code exactly to handle the view of the one piece of news **and nothing else**:

```
def view(request, id):
    news_item = News.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'news/view.html', {"item" : news_item})
```

So, how can i handle another blocks: fetch the data for them and then assign it to the template?

I mean the Python code somewhere in Django, not about templates and its inheritance (i know about it enough).

The most popular and convenient approaches are most appreciable :)

---

As i see you can't understand me, let me show you solutions that i expect to hear from you.

The first solution is to use decorator functions:

```
@load_navigation
@load_recent_news
def view(request, id):
    news_item = News.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'news/view.html', {"item" : news_item})
```

The second solution is to call python function directly in templates:

```
{% block recent_news %}
    {% call "news.views.recent_news" %} 
    {# this will call a python function which will return rendered template with recent news #}
{% endblock %}
```

And the third solution is to use django middleware.

But, to tell you the truth, i don't like any of these approaches. I believe that django has a more convenient way to implement it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781280/how-to-start-forming-a-django-website-and-how-django-structures-pages

Comment: Sorry, this is not what i'm speaking about. I need to know how to fill the templates with data. So i'm speaking about the Python code in Django, not templates.

Comment: Need more explanation then, what do you mean by "handle another blocks"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, sure. Assume that we have 3 blocks at EVERY page on the site: top navigation menu, content area, footer with recent news. So top navigation menu and recent news at the bottom (footer) will be attended at EVERY page, only the content will change according to the requested page. The point is how to fill these 2 blocks with data from DB? How to do that? How to get recent news items and navigation menu items from DB outside the view function (as i mentioned above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,according to your description, I think you can use customized templatetags for the purpose.
Say you want to add recent news in the sidebar (And you have an app called news, while all news stored in a model called Article)

news/templatetags/news.py

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import get_model
register=template.Library();

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_latest_news(context,context_variable):
    context[context_variable]=get_model('News','Article').objects.order_by('-publish_date')[0,10]
    return ''
```

base.html

```
{% load news %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% get_latest_news 'latest' %}
    {% for one in latest %}
        <p>{{one}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's better to start with [simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) than the [complete one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) as it's much simpler and fits with most needs.

Comment: Actually, this is not i'm speaking about. I know about the templates inheritance. The pitfall is how to fill it with the data from DB? How to fetch the recent blog posts, navigation menu pages and then put it in template?

Comment: Thank you, i think i can accept this approach. But calling python functions directly in templates is not the perfect way. May be there is some way to do that not using templates?

Comment: Also, you have to keep you data getter functions in templatetags scripts. I don't think they are made exactly for that purpose. I suppose all these functions which get data from db and process it must be in a model layer.

Comment: You shall have a look into middleware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs If you don't want to do anything in templates. Still, I wonder if there's a 'perfect way' as I learned this approach from Django's own comment framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#comment-template-tags if you call django itself imperfect for their own standard :)

Comment: I believe it's semantically clear and making sense as you can easily see where the data comes from when bumping into these templatetags. Stuffing them together in an outside view or middleware just stirs everything together. Template is for doing its work instead of being strictly clean, take a look at this in "Philosophies and Limitations " http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could override generic detail view (django.views.generic.DetailView)

inherit the view class and override get_context_data() will be what you need to do.